Low sample size in one of the binary classes
I have a dataset with 86 observations, and I want to make inference based on 10 categorical covariates with 22 levels, which results in a model matrix with 12 columns including intercept.
The problem I have is that the outcome variable is binary, and one of the classes only has 9 observations while the other class has 77. Hence, before I naively fit a logistic regression model, I am quite sure that the model will be unstable, having only 9 observations for one of the classes and then splitting these on various covariates. Hence I have considered techniques such as Lasso or bootstrap.
The Lasso needs cross validation to find the penalization parameter $\lambda$, and I have too few observations for cross validation.
Regarding bootstrap, then I have only used bootstrap techniques when calculating sample statistics such as a median or some other. I haven't used this as a way of synthetically creating a bigger dataset.
Does anyone have some advice, or perhaps a solution to how I should go about this?
My goal is to make inference, and identify those covariates that contain the most information and interpret these as predictors in regards to the binary outcome.
Best

As discussed here your effective sample size is $3\times 9 \times 77 / (9 + 77)$, and the minimum sample size needed just to estimate the binary logistic model intercept is $N=96$ when there are no predictors.  Adding predictors only adds to the needed sample size.  Your only hope would be to replace the binary Y with a high-resolution low-error.continuous Y.

Thanks @FrankHarrell. I tried reading it, but I can't find a subsection within section 4 that explains how an effective sample size says something about a minimum sample size.
And do you think that the analysis should be discarded then?

And when I mean discarded, I mean discarding the statistical modelling approach. I could still present empirical observations without speaking of inference.

Rough minimum sample size is described there (but trust the Riley et al references more than that): effective sample size > 15 * p where p is the number of candidate regression coefficients.

The best you can do is to pre-specify a single candidate predictor, e.g. the first principal component of all candidate predictors.  Binary Y has minimum information and you just can’t accomplish what you originally wished for.

Thank you @FrankHarrell
